# Finish cin from keyboard in C++

Tags: c++

I am using for loop to insert string from keyboard but I have a problem to finish input. How to do finish input?

```
    int main()
    {
        vector<string> vec;
        for (string word; cin >> word; vec.push_back(word));
        for (auto &str : vec) for (auto &c : str) c = toupper(c);

        for (int i = 0; i != vec.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (i != 0 && i % 8 == 0) cout << endl;
            cout << vec[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Try the keystrokes  CTRL + D

Comment: Or CTRL + Z (on Windows)

Comment: Ctr+D finish the program, following statement isnot executed

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the an end of file character to the stream.  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works on POSIX systems and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> works on windows.

Comment: Ctr+D finish the program, following statement isnot executed